# How to configure command prompt in GIT with branch name. I get this error message: '-bash: __git_ps1: command not found'

Tags: bash, git, git-branch

I´ve tried to get GIT to show me the directory and branch I´m working on. So that before I type in anything in GIT, when I´m in a project my command prompt would look something like:

```
project name (branch name) >
```

I tried following a tutorial where I was told to make my .bash_profile in my ~ directory look like this:

```
#export PS1='jjberg '
alias ll='ls -lahG'

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

eval "$(rbenv init -)"

if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  source ~/.git-completion.bash
  export PS1='\W$(__git_ps1 "(%s)") > '
fi
```

Problem is, whenever I type a command in GIT, an error message is always attached after every action has been performed. It looks like this:

```
-bash: __git_ps1: command not found
```

Does anybody have any idea on how I would fix this?

Comment: You try to execute this code: `__git_ps1 "(%s)"`

Comment: Does `grep __git_ps1 ~/.git-completion.bash` produce any output?

Comment: Did you define `__git_ps1`? Where?

Comment: On my Ubuntu, `__git_ps1` is defined in `/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt`. On my Windows, it's defined in `D:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh`.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. 
Romeo and jhnc: I tried putting in your code, but I just received the same error message. 
tripleee: Probably not, since I´m getting that error message. But I have no idea where I would have put it. 
ElpieKay: I´m on a Mac, so neither of those ones work for me.

Comment: I guess I´ll just find another tutorial, and try to achieve the same thing that way =)

Answer (score -1):

Won't you like to consider using ZSH? it will automatically detect git repositories just like what you want to achieve.
It will look like something like this:

```
lan-chef-cookbooks git:(master) ✗
```

Btw, I'm using it on Macs but definitely there is a feature of autodetect the repository on other Linux/*nix distros.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip Gilroy! It definitely looks like something I want to investigate further.